# How to open .doc file in ubuntu?

Tags: unity

How to open .doc file in Ubuntu? I can open .docx file in libreoffice but i  can not open .doc file so please help me for them. Using which software i can open .doc file?

Show the image[image] this type of error occurred.

Comment: What happens if you try to open with libreoffice? Please click the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/540448/edit) and add the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose Libreoffice writer in openwith option in the right-click menu. If it doesn't work just rename your filename.doc to filename.docx will work.